# Is there a way for escaping Base64 string for URL Schema?

Tags: ios, url, base64, url-scheme

I'm working with URL schemes in my iOS application. In URL scheme I pass some arguments. One of them is named **image** and its value is Base64 encoded string. My question is, how can I correctly escape that Base64 string so that I can add it as value of argument **image** and still have a valid URL scheme (entire URL needs to be blue)?

Here is the example:

```
myapp://page/test?tel=12345&url=facebook.com&urleee=facebosdcsdok.com
&image=iVBORw0KGgoAAAAkjJIUVJKnjkBUY/oni/IUbJBHBSjks
```

As soon as "**/**" appears the half of URL is blue and treated as URL, but the rest is black and unusable. And that is not valid URL. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: You encode the image URL parameter value like you should do with any other URL parameter value. There are countless examples of doing this.

Comment: I think that this answer is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Yes, it is. You need to encode characters that have special meaning in a URL.

Comment: You mean for example to replace "/ "with "%2F"?

Comment: Yes. But there are existing methods that will encode the whole string as needed. No need to single out the `/`.

Comment: Yes, of course. Thank you for advice.

Comment: By the way, note that the standard character sets, e.g. [`.urlQueryAllowed`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/characterset/1780474-urlqueryallowed), are going to let the `/` and `+` characters, which can appear in the base 64 string, pass unescaped. You'll want to remove those characters from the character set before using that character set in the percent escaping routine.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've managed to make it work with `base64String.removingPercentEncoding`. I'll test it a bit more and check it out.